# Trigger a WebService when the iOS app is in background state

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, background, ibeacon

Is it possible to trigger a web-service and act according to it response when a beacon signal is received in background state ??

I could range for the beacon in background, but before sending a local notification I should check with a web-service whether to notify or not. Can anyone suggest any possible way to do this. Here is the code how it looks now.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
      CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
      beacon = [beacons lastObject];

      if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"Unknown");
      } 
      else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate) {
            NSLog(@"Immediate");
            //Here I should trigger a web-service with the beacon details to check whether to send local notification or not
      } 
      else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear) {
            NSLog(@"Near");
           //Here I should trigger a web-service with the beacon details to check whether to send local notification or not
      } 
      else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar) {
           NSLog(@"Far");
      }
 }
```

Comment: You have about 10 seconds to perform tasks when your app is notified in the background. This should be enough time to query a web service and get a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can be only range in the background if you also set up monitoring.  After a monitoring callback triggers (`didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion`) your app will begin running in the background for about 10 seconds before being supended again.  During this time you will get ranging callbacks if you have your code set up like shown.

If your web service responds quickly enough, this will work.  If the server is slow or you have poor connectivity, the response might not make it back in 10 seconds, in which case the notification will never appear.